# Should I use [weak self] if I don't actually reference self in my completion block?

Tags: swift

I use `[weak self]` when I have a completion block that refers to properties of my class object. However, sometimes I have a completion block that doesn't refer to any properties, but the class object could disappear and deinit. Should I be using `[weak self]` or not? It usually gives a warning `Variable 'self' was written to, but never read` when I do...

```
doSomeFunction() { [weak self] in
   // No references to self here
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Capturing the variables, happens only when you use it internally, a closure will NEVER capture the variables by default (not like Java inner class which ALWAYS captures `this`), so, it you use a variable (including `self`) inside the closure, it is captured.

Also you can manually capture the variables using the `[weak self]`, `[weak your_variable_here]`, `[unowned self]`, `[unowned your_variable_here]`, `[self]` or `[your_variable_here]`

If the compiler tells you `variable "self" is written to but never read from`, it means that you didn't use `self` inside, so it is completely safe not to use `[weak self]`, because `self` will NOT be captured, because it is not used.

`weak self` or `unowned self` is needed only when your closure captures `self`, and escapes the function it is passed to, especially if it is saved in a variable.

Refer to [Closures in Apple's Official Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to. Swift won't do anything with the reference that isn't used so *NOT* using it does the same as using it.

Comment: This is confusing. *"so NOT using it does the same as using it"* doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @rmaddy My understanding from the answer is that swift just ignores `[weak self]` in this instance so there's no point including it in the completion block?

Comment: @Tometoyou Yes, the answer makes perfect sense until the part beginning with "*so NOT..."*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios when it is correct / appropriate to use `[weak self]` in closures:

1) The closure references `self` and is also itself is somehow retained by `self`, or retained by an object that is in turn retained by `self` (circular reference / retain cycle).

2) The closure references `self`, has no form of circular reference with `self`, but the intent is for the closure NOT to prevent `self` from being released if there are no other references to `self`.

In all other cases, there is no need to use `[weak self]`, including cases where the closure has no reference to `self` (or instance members of `self`).